# How does compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec work with multiple compactors?

Tags: cassandra

Recommendation for setting `compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec` says:

> Throttles compaction to the given total throughput across the entire
> system. The faster you insert data, the faster you need to compact in
> order to keep the sstable count down, but in general, setting this to
> 16 to 32 times the rate you are inserting data is more than sufficient.
> Setting this to 0 disables throttling. Note that this account for all types
> of compaction, including validation compaction.*

Does it have some limitations or its only depends on insertion rate?

How can i measure insertion rate?

Does this throughput sets for every compactor

```
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec = 64
compactor1 = 64
compactor2 = 64
```

Or splits equally

```
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec = 64
compactor1 = 32
compactor2 = 32
```

Or its changing at runtime for every compactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it have some limitations or its only depends on insertion rate?

It's mainly about write throughput and overall compute resources.  The thing is, that high amounts of write throughput actually *cause* compaction.  The recommendation about write throughput (insertion rate) is really about making sure that compaction doesn't fall behind.

And that's a *GOOD* thing!  Trust me, in that you want compaction to run and not fall behind.  Uncompacted SSTable files cause read latency from having so many files to look through and manage.

The bigger problem that I've seen, is that a batch job runs, inserts a bunch of data, and causes compaction to run.  The resource drain on compute resources taken by compaction then interferes with future writes as well as reads, by increasing the latency of both operations.

One solution was that we realized our usage on one cluster was very, very cyclical, starting at 6am and ending after 11pm.  We used to do a `nodetool setcompactionthroughput 256` at midnight, followed by a `nodetool setcompactionthroughput 8` in the morning.  That higher setting allowed compactions to run almost unencumbered at night while being set to a "trickle" during the day (so as not to interfere with normal operations).

> How can I measure insertion rate?

Not sure what you're using for monitoring your cluster, but you should be able to pull writes-per-second off of the `org.apache.cassandra.metrics` MBean.